# Just wanted to share some recent software that might be of use to PF

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/36418/is-there-a-body-animator-i-can-use-to-demonstrate-exercise-movements) recently on Physical Fitness (PF) wanting to know if there was a way to show animations of physical human movements within questions, so they can be shared within the PF community, and I came across Standford's [OpenSim project](https://simtk.org/projects/opensim). Refer to the original post to see a video of capabilities, but it's close to what I had envisioned. What do you think?

Comment: Your URL doesn't resolve for me. Maybe https://simtk.org/projects/opensim?

Comment: Please see the discussion I started on software/scope.

Comment: @JohnP, and how do I do that?

Comment: @uwnojpjm - Read it on meta?